# How to prevent a race condition when loading on-demand JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript

To speed up things, my web application loads JavaScript files for certain features on-demand using jQuery's ajax call. I've encountered a race condition problem, though. For example, file B.js depends on file A.js. I've configured a list like list=[A.js,B.js] and I iterate over this list and asynchronously get the scripts. How can I prevent this race condition?

The code that loads the JavaScript files is something like:

```
loadJS: function(url) {
    $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'script', success: function(){}});
}
```

Comment: minify and concatenate the two files into C.js.  No race condition if you're only pulling one file.

Comment: Don't use ajax for loading those scripts dependent upon others?

Comment: Why not use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: Simply wait to a.js to return before you send a request to b.js.

Comment: I want to avoid minifying because it's annoying during development. RequireJS does not have functionality to load on-demand, it loads in the beginning.

Comment: Show your current code, and we can suggest simple alterations to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of dependency management is not incredibly hard. Without getting too much into how to properly abstract it, if you have an array of files to load, on your ajax callback (which I assume is downloading the contents of the js file to a string) save the string in another array until you download the contents of all the files. Once all the files are in memory, add them to the dom in order.

You will want to add some extra stuff like handling failures and the like but that is a general outline of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you asynchronously load files 1 and 2 using:

```
function load(URI) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URI,
        dataType: "script",
    });
}
```

and file 2 has dependency on file 1 then the files can be loaded asynchronously as:

```
load(url1)
  .then(load(url2));
```

and if file 2 doesn't have dependency on file 1 then they can be loaded as:

```
$.when(load(url1), load(url2))
    .then(function(e) { // both scripts loaded successfully});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add script tags instead of making ajax calls:

```
var scripts = ['a.js', 'b.js'],
    idx;

for(idx in scripts) {
    if(scripts.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
        document.write(['<script src="', scripts[idx], '"></script>'].join(''));
    }
}
```

Scripts will be loaded asynchronously, but executed synchronously in the order you added them.